# Emacs23 with "window height too small"

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu

The new emacs23 gives me

> ("Window width 0 too small (after splitting)"))

whenever I load ECB or tabbar. Seems to be introduces after updating from Kubuntu intrepid to jaunty. Any hint how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs-snapshot/+bug/374054) apparently... Until a fix is released, the easiest solution would be to run emacs21.

If you're willing to patch & recompile, I also found a potential patch [here](http://www.nabble.com/Integrate-sr-speedbar.el-with-speedbar.el-td21094426.html), although I can't confirm if it works or not.

```
-----------------------
diff -c /tmp/sr-speedbar.el\~ /tmp/sr-speedbar.el                                    
--- /tmp/sr-speedbar.el~   2008-11-06 07:57:08.000000000 -0800                                    
+++ /tmp/sr-speedbar.el    2008-11-06 07:59:21.000000000 -0800                                    
@@ -270,16 +270,17 @@
   (interactive)                                                                                              
   (let ((current-window (selected-window)))                                                                  
     (if (and sr-speedbar-window                                                                              
-           speedbar-buffer                                                                                    
-           (window-live-p sr-speedbar-window) ;when `sr-speedbar-window' visible                              
-           (buffer-live-p speedbar-buffer))   ;and contain `speedbar-buffer'                                  
-       (sr-speedbar-select-window)                                                                            
-      (if (> (current-window-take-width) 1) ;if width of `sr-speedbar-window' is a valid value                
-         (setq sr-speedbar-width (current-window-take-width))) ;remember it make next restore same width      
-      (bury-buffer)                                                                                          
-      (if (and current-window                                                                                
-              (window-live-p current-window))                                                                
-        (select-window current-window)))))                                                                    
+            speedbar-buffer                                                                                  
+            (window-live-p sr-speedbar-window) ;when `sr-speedbar-window' visible                            
+            (buffer-live-p speedbar-buffer))   ;and contain `speedbar-buffer'                                
+       (progn                                                                                                
+         (sr-speedbar-select-window)                                                                          
+         (if (> (current-window-take-width) 1) ;if width of `sr-speedbar-window' is a valid value            
+             (setq sr-speedbar-width (current-window-take-width))) ;remember it make next restore same width  
+         (bury-buffer)                                                                                        
+         (if (and current-window                                                                              
+                  (window-live-p current-window))                                                            
+             (select-window current-window))))))
```

Comment: If I use LANG=C instead of "de", emacs works as expected. Is your bugfix related to that?